# Override regional format setting in iphone app

Tags: iphone, settings, regional-settings

Is there any way we can override regional format setting and language from application?  I am not able to get to the point answer of this question.

so changing region from app will change the iphone region setting.

Can anybody help it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't change iPhone's region settings and language from your app with current SDK (without user interactions).  Rather you can ask user to change it from Settings App.